# Which child will execute first when you call fork() and wait() multiple times?

Tags: c, process, fork, wait

When you call `fork()` multiple times, and then call `wait()`; which child will be executed first? The first, or second child?

```cpp
int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    t_d f;
    static int ii;
    int fd[2];
    int pid;
    int pid1;

    if (ac != 5)
        return (1);
    else
    {
        // f.fd1 = creat_open_file(av[1], 0);
        // f.fd2 = creat_open_file(av[4], 1);
        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
            exit (1);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
            exit (1);
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            ft_printf("chi i == %d\n", ii++);
            child_process_(av[2], env, fd);
        }
        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 == 0)
        {
            ft_printf("par i == %d\n", ii++);
            parent_process_(av[3], env, fd);
        }
        // waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        // waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        wait(NULL);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

In my code, the first child is executed first, but I want to know the details as to why the first is who is executed first and not the second child.

For my expecting, I think the second child is who needs to be executed first.

Comment: It's not clear you mean to call `fork` twice, based on your two `*_process_` functions. Say you start with P1: it calls `fork` to create P2. P2 then executes `child_process_`. Now P1 *and* P2 call `fork`, creating P3 and P4. P1 and P2 both call `parent_process_` All 4 processes then call `close` and `wait`.

Comment: Did you mean to use an `if-else`, with P1 calling `parent_process` and `wait`, and `P2` calling `child_process_` and exiting?

Comment: Without enforced sequencing, the order in which the processes execute is undefined.  Enforced sequencing would be operations such as `wait()` or `pause()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute first" and "execute second"?  The live processes in the system execute *at the same time* for most intents and purposes, especially on systems with multiple execution units.

Comment: I mean by the terms execute first and second, after find wait() then, the child process must be executed before the parent, I m new in this chapter of programming, so here I think it must be execute the second child and then back to the first child and then execute the parent, (I m beginner at this chapter, so I m sorry for any missunderstanding, and any one find me lost, guide me and thanks for all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have a fixed order of operation, the reason the first child is more likely going to be executed before the second child is just because it was created first and probably requested cpu time before the 2nd one. In the way your code is structured all childs will execute lines of code outside of the if because you're not exiting so the first child process will actually call fork and both will call wait(NULL) 2 times, including the parent process. Be careful with that.

Comment: with some research yesterday I get this point thats you clarify, thanks to you bro!